# sortable column with displaytag

Tags: jsp, format, jquery-ui-sortable, displaytag

My problem basically is that I want to display records in a table, for that use display tag, a field of the record corresponds to a numeric value, and I want to be shown in the following format: $ 4.258, for this I do next:

```
<fmt:setLocale value="en_US"/>
<display:column title="Monto" sortable="true" style="font-size: 12px;">
   $<fmt:formatNumber value="${datos.monto}" />
</display:column>
```

But this way the sortable is not working well, but if I put it this way:

```
<display:column title="Monto" property="monto" sortable="true" style="font-size: 12px;"/>
```

The sortable works well, but I have not in the format that I need, what it shows is: `4258.0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the format as follows:

```
<display:column title="Monto" property="monto" format="$ {0,number,0,000.00}" sortable="true" style="font-size: 12px;"/>
```

[You can use MessageFormat pattern](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/11/displaytag/tagreference.html#column).

Comment: Hello, I had already tried that, but without $ sign (format="{0,number,0,000}"), because with that sign produce an error, and I do not get the format i need, it puts a dot (4.258), and I want (4,258), but I failure to place the $ sign =(.... thanks for your answer...I've got half of what I need

Comment: So my answer doesn't give you the desired output? Did you specify the format as a currency [0,000.00]?

Comment: Mmmm...!!! I thought I did it with <fmt:setLocale value="en_US"/>... is that correct??

Comment: Sure. But did you add format="${0,number,0,000.00}" to your statement?

Comment: Yes, first I write format="${0,number,0,000.00}" and the browser shows an error that contains incorrect expressions, but if I remove the $ sign, like this: format="{0,number,0,000.00}", the browser displays 1358.00 and I need to display $ 1.358. I have searched google many solutions, but I can not fix =(

Comment: put a space between $ and { : `format="$ {0,number,0,000.00}"`

Comment: Yes, it works!!.....=)....Thank you!!....I leave it like this: format="$ {0,number,0,000}", because I don't need the decimal... now I need the separation of thousands, now is 1.425, but I have to display something like this 1,425

Comment: Display this: $ 9.406,00...... I need to display something like that: $ 9,406....I've tried many ways....how do I get???

Comment: Ok, I will try to solve it, but I have a great advance, thank you very much for your help!!! =)